# Discussion list, alert email should only have "something is changed" no details because of gdpr

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Is there anyway we can change RSS settings or alert emails sharepoint sends to end users ?

We only want to send url to spsite and "something has changed" text nothing else for example no body and no subject title.

At the moment it sends Subject, Body etc..

Comment: I want to do it using powershell please

Answer (score 1):

1. List Ribbon Tab
2. Alert Me > Set an Alert
3. set the *change type* to **Existing items are modified**

[image]

Comment: Chris thanks, but I think you misunderstood me, I want email sent to user only have text saying that something is changed, not all details

Comment: I also updated my question to be more clear, sorry for confusion

Comment: Then this can be accomplished with a SharePoint designer workflow as the out of the box alerts will always send all the information so the users know what fields were modified. I'm not sure about the RSS feed but the email can be done though a workflow.